# ClassNotFoundException: SharedByteArrayInputStream within mail.jar

Tags: java, tomcat, exception, classloader

I'm having an issue accessing a class from a jar file ...
[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykVNK.png)

As you can see in the stacktrace, line 106 in NetEnviaEmail class is causing an exception due to a problem loading SharedByteArrayInputStream

Line 106 `Message message = new MimeMessage (mailSession);`

This MailMessage class as well as the Session class (mailSession variable) are both imported from mail.jar (version 1.4)

The lib structure follows below

[mail.jar structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUYsQ.png)

MimeMessage was imported specifying javax.mail.internet package.

Notice that according to stacktrace the package in which tomcat is trying to find the class is 'com.sun.mail.util', when it should be 'javax.mail.util'
I can't understand why the tomcat classloader does not look for the class in the right package.

I'm using java 8 and tomcat 9, but this code was originally written in java 7 and older versions of tomcat.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution

When using Tomcat 9 on Eclipse apparently it's not enough to simply remove a jar file from your buildpath in order to prevent it from being loaded

I had to mannualy delete the j2ee.jar file from source folder, which was being used in runtime by Tomcat to load javax.mail.internet package